# Firebase Firestore update data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using `firebase firestore` to create my website, this is one sample of document:

[image]

As you can see, I have a field call `commentList` and its type is `array`, now I want to push more document in the the array and this is how I did (and it not work out, of course):

```
const {db} = require('../util/admin');

exports.add__comment = (req, res, next) => {
  const {comment, displayName, uid} = req.body;
  const {id} = req.params;

  return db
    .collection('instagram__posts')
    .doc(id)
    .set(
      {
        commentList: [
          {comment, uid, displayName, createAt: new Date().toISOString()},
        ],
      },
      {merge: true}
    )
    .then((doc) => {
      return res.status(200).json({message: 'comment created', doc});
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).json({err});
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

Instead of adding more document to `commentList`, it replace all current documents with new data. Please help me and pardon me for my bad English. Once again thank you so much and have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Try push element to direct path.

```js
firebase.firestore()
  .collection('instagram__posts')
  .doc(id)
  .collection('commentList')
  .add({comment, uid, displayName, createAt: new Date().toISOString()})
```

Show details here: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#update-data

Comment: thank you, I tried your way, but it not help, I think it keyword `collection('commentList')` is the problemt

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add another element to a list type field, use `update()` and `FieldValue.arrayUnion()`, as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

```
  db
    .collection('instagram__posts')
    .doc(id)
    .update({
      commentList: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({comment, uid, displayName, createAt: new Date().toISOString()})
    })
```

Comment: look like it is promising but it returned me this error: `Error: Update() requires either a single JavaScript object or an alternating list of field/value pairs that can be followed by an optional precondition. Value for argument "dataOrField" is not a valid Firestore document. Couldn't serialize object of type "FieldValue$1" (found in field "commentList"). Firestore doesn't support JavaScript objects with custom prototypes (i.e. objects that were created via the "new" operator).`